# Porque no me funcionan los dialogos en Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript, cordova

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pantalla-quiz',
  templateUrl: './pantalla-quiz.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pantalla-quiz.page.scss'],
})
export class PantallaQuizPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialogs: Dialogs) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

 hola(){

  this.dialogs.confirm('hi','my',['hi','hi'])
  .then(() => console.log('Dialog dismissed'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error displaying dialog', e));

  }

}
```

Aquí lo que hago es un dialogo de confirmación y me aparece el siguiente error.
Haciendo uso e los dialogos en Ionic cordova, y ejecutando el código desde un navegador web. El error a lo mejor me lo a porque no compilo desde un teléfono  movil? Si saben algo al respecto, espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
vendor.js:78655 Native: tried calling Dialogs.confirm, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ common.js:290
main.js:1808 Error displaying dialog
```

Comment: El error te indica que cordova no está disponible y efectivamente es porque estás ejecutándolo desde el navegador, para hacer uso de plugins de cordova tienes que ejecutarlo en un dispositivo o emulador.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.Realmente pensé que sería algo por el estilo, pero al no estar seguro prefería preguntar. ;)